# Array push in multidimensional array also pushing in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using `array_push` to add values to a multidimensional array.

My code looks like:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $subArr){
  $tmp[$key] = array();

  foreach($subArr as $value){
    foreach($filter as $prod){
      if($prod['key_value'] == $key."_".$value){
        echo "array_push(tmp[{$key}], {$prod['id']})<br>";
        array_push($tmp[$key], $prod['id']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`$arr` holds:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 821
        )

)
```

`$filter` is to big to post here, but it's an array with product ID's and the filter key `key_value`.

Now when I run this code, it's output is:

```
array_push(tmp[4], 180)
array_push(tmp[4], 172)
array_push(tmp[4], 182)
array_push(tmp[4], 116)
array_push(tmp[4], 170)
array_push(tmp[4], 169)
array_push(tmp[4], 144)
array_push(tmp[4], 145)
array_push(tmp[4], 187)
array_push(tmp[4], 124)
array_push(tmp[4], 198)
array_push(tmp[4], 148)
array_push(tmp[4], 163)
array_push(tmp[4], 195)
array_push(tmp[4], 194)
array_push(tmp[4], 196)
```

The `$tmp` array however looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 180
    [1] => 172
    [2] => 182
    [3] => 116
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 180
            [1] => 172
            [2] => 182
            [3] => 116
            [4] => 170
            [5] => 169
            [6] => 144
            [7] => 145
            [8] => 187
            [9] => 124
            [10] => 198
            [11] => 148
            [12] => 163
            [13] => 195
            [14] => 194
            [15] => 196
        )

    [5] => 169
    [6] => 144
    [7] => 145
    [8] => 187
    [9] => 124
    [10] => 198
    [11] => 148
    [12] => 163
    [13] => 195
    [14] => 194
    [15] => 196
)
```

All productID's should be in `tmp[4]`, but why are they also just in `tmp`?

Comment: Could you show a couple values inside `$filter`?

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the code that you have shown. Are you sure that `$tmp` itself is empty when you start?

Comment: The problem was that `$tmp` was not an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but it was too big for a comment.

I don't know why or how, but your `$tmp` contained the following when your loop started:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 180
    [1] => 172
    [2] => 182
    [3] => 116
    [4] => 170
    [5] => 169
    [6] => 144
    [7] => 145
    [8] => 187
    [9] => 124
    [10] => 198
    [11] => 148
    [12] => 163
    [13] => 195
    [14] => 194
    [15] => 196
)
```

Make sure that `$tmp` is an *empty* array when you start.

Comment: That was the fix. Just missed it!